# How to do that command yii migrate would work on all module files?

Tags: yii2, migration, migrate

I'm musing my migrations, but I have couple migration files in directory: `@app/migrations` and other migration files in `@app/modules/module_name/migrations`. When I'm using `yii migrate` it just only migrates the files of `@app/migrations`. How to do that it would migrate all the files (including both or more directories)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `migrationPath` parameter, specified here: [Yii2 Migrations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html#using-command-line-options).

Since version 2.0.12 you can use array for loading migrations from multiple sources.

Global setting:

Instead of entering the same option values every time you run the migration command, you may configure it once for all in the application configuration like shown below:

```
return [
    'controllerMap' => [
        'migrate' => [
            'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\MigrateController',
            'migrationTable' => 'backend_migration',
            'migrationPath' => [
                                // here your config
            ]
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: I'm using `migrationPath` when I'm migrating my modules. But what I need to do is that all the files (module migrations and basic migrations) would migrate just only by using `yii migrate`